# Why does reducing this lazy sequence slow down this Clojure program 20x?

Tags: clojure, fibonacci, reduce, lazy-sequences, take

I have a Clojure program that returns the sum of a lazy sequence of `even` Fibonacci numbers below `n`:

```
(defn sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below-1 [n]
  (defn fib [a b] (lazy-seq (cons a (fib b (+ b a)))))
  (reduce + (take-while (partial >= n) (take-nth 3 (fib 0 1)))))

(time (dotimes [n 1000] (sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below-1 4000000))) ;; => "Elapsed time: 98.764msecs"
```

It's not very efficient. But if I don't reduce the sequence and simply return a list of the values `(0 2 8 34 144...)` it can do its job 20x faster:

```
(defn sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below-2 [n]
  (defn fib [a b] (lazy-seq (cons a (fib b (+ b a)))))
  (take-while (partial >= n) (take-nth 3 (fib 0 1))))


(time (dotimes [n 1000] (sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below-2 4000000))) ;; => "Elapsed time: 5.145msecs"
```

**Why is `reduce` so costly to this lazy Fibonacci sequence, and how can I speed it up without abandoning idiomatic Clojure?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference in the execution time is a result of lazyness. In `sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below-2` you only produce a lazy seq of Fibonacci numbers which is not realised (`dotimes` only calls `sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below-2` to create a lazy sequence, but does not evaluate all of its contents). So in fact your second `time` expression doesn't return a list of values but a lazy seq that will produce its elements only when you ask for them.

To force realisation of the lazy sequence you can use `dorun` if you don't need to preserve it as a value or `doall` if you want to get the realised seq (be careful with inifinite seqs).

If you measure the second case with `sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below-2` wrapped in `dorun` you will get time comparable to `sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below-1`.

Results from my machine:

```
(time (dotimes [n 1000] (sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below-1 4000000))) ;; => "Elapsed time: 8.544193 msecs"

(time (dotimes [n 1000] (dorun (sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below-2 4000000)))) ;; => "Elapsed time: 8.012638 msecs"
```

I also noticed that you defined your `fib` function with `defn` inside another `defn`. You shouldn't do that as `defn` will always define function at the top level in your namespace. So your code should look like:

```
(defn fib [a b] (lazy-seq (cons a (fib b (+ b a)))))

(defn sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below-1 [n]
  (reduce + (take-while (partial >= n) (take-nth 3 (fib 0 1)))))

(defn sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below-2 [n]
  (take-while (partial >= n) (take-nth 3 (fib 0 1))))
```

If you do want to define a locally scoped function you can take a look at [`letfn`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/letfn).

Comment: I'm confused by your answer. The `-1` method was slow to begin with. How did you get it to perform in 8.5msecs on your machine? Simply a faster machine?

Comment: Probably. Did you try to run the second test with `dorun`? What results did you get?

Comment: ETA: adding dorun puts it back at 90msecs

Comment: try this one and see how quick it runs: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/475ed4cdcbff303117b733ac4046d63d

Comment: That one runs < 5msecs on my machine.

Comment: EDIT: I had a typo. On my machine if I use `dorun` it takes ~90msecs again. Thanks for clarifying! But why is laziness so much slower than the gist I posted? I'm new to clojure: why would I ever use a lazy sequence if it's 20x slower than `loop`?

Comment: `lazy-seq` (or eager `seq` instead of just `loop`ing) adds an overhead of wrapping all your numbers into a datastructure instead of just using bare numbers. `lazy-seq` is useful if you want to have an abstract way to generate a sequence elements but you don't know how many of them you will need. It's also composable (unlike your `sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below-3` which just knows how to calculate the sum of n Fibonacci numbers). Your Fibonacci seq can be used in many different scenarios: you can `take` just first `n` elements, `drop` first `n` elements, `filter` only `even?` elements etc

Answer (score -1):

**Comment**

You can refactor your functions - and give them better names - thus:

```
(defn fib [a b] (lazy-seq (cons a (fib b (+ b a)))))

(defn even-fibonaccis-below [n]
  (take-while (partial >= n) (take-nth 3 (fib 0 1))))

(defn sum-of-even-fibonaccis-below [n]
  (reduce + (even-fibonaccis-below n)))
```

This is easier to understand and therefore to answer.